# Is it possible to set different z-index values for table rows?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

I need to create a table fixed on the bottom of screen (I'm so far now) and I'd like the rows to have different z-index values, because I want them to look like 'folders' where images are sliding down into it. Please have a look on the picture below, it illustrates exactly the expecting effect. Pictures (all inserted in a long sliding div) need also different z-index settings to 'go into' folders (in fact, they have to slide under the corresponding 'folder').

In your opinion, is it possible inside the table (and inside the div for images) or should I create tables (with only one row) one below the other ? This would be complicated to apply on pictures because they're randomly positioned into a 'scroller' (refers to the div mentioned above). Any example would be more than welcome!

[image: images sliding 'into' table rows]

Comment: You can use opacity (CSS)

Comment: This is possible. But you might be better off using divs instead of a table or seperate tables so you have more control over each. In your picture, each 'row' seems to contain only a string, so it's more like a list than a table. You'll have to show the html structure and css for us to be able to answer more specifically.

Comment: You should try to avoid tables instead of divs unless they are really necessary.

Comment: @Satindersingh : In which way should I use opacity ? I already read this somewhere.

Comment: @Shilly : Please find a JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/tuqxxesp/ (I reduce the code just to keep what's necessary, and I also add a picture hosted on the web so It not really looks the same than original but I can send you a WeTransfer If you prefer)

Comment: @LeonFreire : I'm not sure if tables are the best for what I've to do, I'm still wondering and looking for advices. Here's a further step of what I need to achieve, maybe it could help to decide : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2017/09/1488461887-capture-d-ecran-1058.png (the 'table' goes on top and roll out on title click, for each section)

Comment: @MarjorieOber I think what you are looking for is a method to create an Accordion. Am I right? See if this is what you are looking for: [Accordions](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp). With this method you will be able to put whatever you want inside each of these "tabs".

Comment: @LeonFreire : Yes that's exactly what I need, thank you ! But I'm not so far, I'm still stucking on this z-index issue. To explain better : First, pictures have to 'fall down' into 'folders', then, after all the stuff has slide down (or has been scrolled), the 'folders' go on top of screen and can be 'opened' to see each project more in details.

Comment: @MarjorieOber No problem. Give it a try. Hmmm... I think I understand. But I can't look further into this without the code. :/

Comment: @LeonFreire : I can now figure this out for the 'table' part, but how will I be able to apply it on the 'images' div ? (please have a look on its structure in fiddle above)

Comment: @LeonFreire : Please follow this link to download file (the one I'm working on) https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3bc99daffc9503370c30a5c18fb55f7a20170302140914/d9a7d55d132699865e0dd6cd7c29ee0920170302140914/725772

Comment: @MarjorieOber I'm sorry, but I'm unable to do it with table rows. I ran multiple simulations and did some research, but I don't think its possible. I think that for the desired results you will need to turn to divs. If you wish to change your approach, here is an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5wkz38wh/)

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm totally okay to change the approach, I'm working on your accordion proposal, and maybe some code you set in your fiddle will help to accomplish ! I'll send you something later but I finally think that I'll need more help to handle the 'images' part (you know wrapped in a scroller, etc.). But really a huge thank you !

Comment: @MarjorieOber No problem. Glad to help! :)

Comment: @LeonFreire : 
 
So here I am : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f49b33be0d88b30c56f3d678f5ca16ad20170302175752/5cdff91a2b439a2076314c65c61e027220170302175752/6b9834 I tried to reproduce what you did in your fiddle but there's something wrong and I can't find it out ! It's like it doesn't apply to last 'rows', I suspect a conflict in the ':nth-child()' part but I never use it so I'm not sure of doing well ! If you prefer, we could start a chat instead of commenting, as you want !

Comment: @MarjorieOber You are more than welcome to open a chat. I just won't be 100% available as I'm at work right now. But I may give you a hint right away. You don't need to use `nth-child` if each of them has a unique class. Just use: `div .accordeon.cellule1` and on.

Comment: @LeonFreire : No problem ! Only answer to me when you have some time ! Unfortunately, I haven't enough reputation on Stack to open a chat, but I'm okay to use some other social networks if you don't mind. I try to make it work ;)

Comment: @MarjorieOber No problem. I don't think I have enough either. For now, try what I told you and replace the `nth-child`s with your class tags and all the rows will work. I'm having a hard time figuring the z-index problem with the pictures too. I see it only works when they don't have parent divs. So I think you should open a new question more specific for that after you have the changes done.

Comment: We can now say the 'row' part works, but I'im not able to solve the pictures issue, someone gave me a hint with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/hfgtxzaq/ but I didn't managed to apply it to my code. You can find me on Facebook (https://www.facebook.com/marjorie.ober.9?fref=ts) or here's my email adress : marjorie.ober@gmail.com. Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will work 100% for you since I'm not entering too much in how your scroll works, but I'll give you a few tips I've tested here and it actually works, but it might have you doing a few changes on some other things. Here it goes:

First of all, as I mentioned, change the `nth-child` part in your css to these tags:

```
div .accordeon.cellule1 {
    z-index: 801;
}

div .accordeon.cellule2 {
    z-index: 803;
}

div .accordeon.cellule3 {
    z-index: 805;
}

div .accordeon.cellule4 {
    z-index: 807;
}

div .accordeon.cellule5 {
    z-index: 809;
}
```

Now, the complicated part that may be kind of frustrating, but experiencing it was all I got. I think you will have to make a scroller for each picture to be something like this, or else the z-index will not work because all of them get the z-index from the parent. This is how I changed the CSS:

### IT'S ONLY AN EXAMPLE

```
<div id="scroller-wrapper" class="scroller-wrapper"  style="z-index: 804">
   <div id="scroller" class="scroller slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile1" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/ceaac.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scroller-wrapper" class="scroller-wrapper"  style="z-index: 806">
   <div id="scroller" class="scroller slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile2" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/ceaac2.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scroller-wrapper" class="scroller-wrapper"  style="z-index: 802">
   <div id="scroller" class="scroller slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile3" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/ceaac3.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scroller-wrapper" class="scroller-wrapper"  style="z-index: 800">
   <div id="scroller" class="scroller slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile5" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/ceaac5.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scroller-wrapper" class="scroller-wrapper"  style="z-index: 808">
   <div id="scroller" class="scroller slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile6" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/clic_clac.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="scroller-wrapper" class="scroller-wrapper" style="z-index: 802">
   <div id="scroller" class="scroller slidedown">
         <div id="img-defile7" class="img-defile">
            <img src="img/heschung.jpg"/>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice I turned all IDs to Classes for CSS purposes (although i kept all IDs as well for your animation purposes), and of course in the CSS I replaced the `#` for dots. Maybe this is not the ideal way for you, but feel free to comment below. For now, its all I have to make the pictures fit in their folders. Hope it helps you somehow! :)

Comment: Thank you so much @LeonFreire ! It works indeed and you were right, now the problem is different and affects the 'scroller-wrappers', because they're all overlaying, I'm not able at all to scroll into it (that worked with all pictures in a wrapper, not with a wrapper under each 'scroller', but sounds quite logical !). I guess I have to find a way to make each wrapper leave page after scrolled or something like that ! Don't worry, I will open a new topic and leave you alone, I took enough of your time !

Comment: In any case, Thank you from the bottom of my heart, I wish I could return you the favor one day ;)

Comment: @MarjorieOber Haha... No problem! Don't worry! I'm here to help! I guess I'll find your next question! Haha.. ^^